# Laptop damaged bios?

Tags: bios

I have a Dell latitude laptop which I accidentally power cycled during boot. Now it won't boot at all.The Dell logo shows, but then the screen turns black - computer doesn't shut down, fan still makes a slight noise but it doesn't enter bios.

Spamming F2 gets me to the system setup menu. Inserting a windows disc does nothing (even after changing boot sequence).

Guessing I have to reset bios somehow, but I'm not sure how?

Comment: Do you have the exact model of your Dell Latitude Laptop? System Setup Menu = BIOS?

Comment: If you still can get into the BIOS there should be an option to load Default settings, make notes of the current settings if the BIOS is not a familiar place for you. I would suggest to try to boot off of a CD/DVD or USB Stick first though to narrow down the cause. It might just be a case of a damaged Windows Installation on the HDD.

Comment: Sounds like you are confusing the BIOS with the Windows Boot loader. From your description, your BIOS sounds operable because you can change the boot order. Dell laptops use F10 to prompt for a boot choice (hitting F10 repeatedly during power on). If there, when you pick CD/DVD and your "windows disc" doesn't boot, it may be that that disc isn't bootable.

Answer (score 1):

Remove battery and charger from laptop - Leave out for a minute. Place battery and charger back in then switch on. Should boot ok.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that you could not kill your BIOS or even damage CMOS settings by this way, because you did not touch them when you power cycled. What really could happen that some data on HDD could be correupted, like file table, boot record and etc. Run Live CD from optical or USB drive, if it runs that will prove that BIOS is ok and you will be going to restore your currently installed OS with its file table and MBR or just simply reinstall OS.

If you have your data that needs to be saved anyway then it might worth saving it first. That involves other big explanations. It is doable. However if you need to save your precious data, don't install anything to this drive. First read it back.